# User model is not saving create_user instances

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I have made a form having fields of personal information and login information as one

models.py

```
 class EmployeeModel(models.Model)
        employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True,help_text='Employee ID should not be same')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
        password_confirm = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = employeeModel
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```
User = get_user_model()
def create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = employeeForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            User= get_user_model()
            user= User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
            authenticate(request,username=username,email=email,password=password)

            form.save()
            return redirect('emp_list')
    else:
        form = employeeForm()
    return render(request,'create_employee.html',{'form':form})
```

Its not showing any error but User.objects.all() shows only superuser not the users i created though this form. Those users i have created in this form are  are showing up in Employee.objects.get(username='foo')

So what to do? I cant login through those non_superusers. it throws invalid login error. How to fix this?